# Allow multiple users to enter data in windows application form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When multiple users open my windows application, it shows a warning saying it(accdb) is already in use.  How do I allow multiple users to make entries using my application simultaneously?
The database which my application is using is in shared mode.

edit :
here's a snap of the error that pops up:
[image]

Comment: You mean how to keep the data in sync?  What have you tried?

Comment: This is not enough information to definitely tell what your problem is, but my guess is that you need to split the ms access database into a back end and front end. MS Access supports splitting so that there is one database on a server share, and each user gets their own application which is just the forms that point to the back end data.

Comment: Do have a look at the error (image)

Comment: use MS SQL, although you might find it hard to set up at the start, in the long run it will be better for your app, and you can do so many more things.

Comment: Your connection string is apparently opening the Access database for exclusive use so modify it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the connection string you are using and the relevant code that causes the error.

Comment: here is the connection string -  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\510101\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ErrorTracking\ErrorTracking\\ErrorTracking.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=***********"

Answer (score 0):

You may consider making the application talk to database, and then allowing the users to use their own copy of the application. This way, only one user is using the application, but multiple instances access the database.

Comment: splitting it once and then connecting it to my application instead of the main accdb would do my job?